# making shorter the source parsing xml in jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

This is what i parsed from xml, but it's too long. Does anyone know how to make it shorter?
there is a change of the number at "charList()" and structure of "if".

`var charList1;
var charList2;
    var charList3;`
    `var charList4;
    var charList5;`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "XMLFile1.xml",
    async: false,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        $(xml).find('list').each(function () {

            obj = $(this).find("title");

            if (obj.text() == "1") {
                charList1 = (obj.next().text());
            } else if (obj.text() == "2") {
                charList2 = (obj.next().text());
            } else if (obj.text() == "3") {
                charList2 = (obj.next().text());
            } else if (obj.text() == "4") {
                charList2 = (obj.next().text());
            } else if (obj.text() == "5") {
                charList2 = (obj.next().text());                
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe use a `switch`. Not shorter, but it will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to rethink your data structures (using parallel scalar or array variables with numeric suffixes on their names is an almost certain sign that you really should be using an aggregate structure like an array or an object). Offhand, it sounds like you really want an array indexed by the (numeric) value of `obj.text()`; something like

```
var charList=[];
$(xml).find('list').each(function () {
  obj = $(this).find("title");
  if (obj>= "1" && obj <= "5") { // use your own sanity check
    charlist[parseInt(obj, 10)] = obj.next().text();
  }
}
```

Note, though, that making an AJAX call synchronous is seldom a good idea (it will completely lock up the browser until it finishes, and when you're talking to another system you have no guarantee that it *will* finish). If you make it asynchronous (that's what the first A in AJAX stands for), you'll need to pass the accumulated value of `charlist` into a callback, since it won't be available when you "fall through" your AJAX call.

Comment: thank you for answering. i have just started to study Jquery. it's hard to understand what you give me a advice. How can i change this to array?? i have to use "charList(there has to be numbers here),"  because the other structures use "charList." therefore, i have to declare charList out of Jquery